# Wordpress - Woocommerce: background noise after rescaling a transparent png

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, png, transparent

When I **upload an image to wordpress**, there is a strange behaviour. The original file (either exported from photoshop or optimized via tinypng.com) stays clean.

**But the resized images (all sizes incl. theme & woocommerce) have all a noise pattern inside the transparent background. This appears when I see the file inside the shop on a white (`#fffff`) background.**

**How to reproduce:**

- Export a transparent object from Photoshop as png-24, reduce to 25%, bicubic calculation
- Upload this file to the Wordpress media backend
- Look at the shop overview
- Result: [Bottle with transparent background (png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEmD3.png)

This Bug is only visible on some screens. On Mac less than on a default screen. It seems that when I use **GD** instead of **imagick** the noise becomes less. But it is still visible.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is created by the resizing. It seems **both imagick and php-gd produce the noise** on Debian Strech.

So the solution is to use the original file not being resized and everything works fine.

### Get the existing sizes inside your theme

Get the formats inside your`page.php` by temporarily adding `<pre><?php var_dump(get_intermediate_image_sizes()) ?></pre>`. It will return an array of sizes you need to remove.

### Remove the broken sizes

```
add_action('init', 'solidcreation_remove_plugin_image_sizes');

function solidcreation_remove_plugin_image_sizes() {
  remove_image_size('shop_catalog');
  remove_image_size('shop_single');
  remove_image_size('woocommerce_thumbnail');
  remove_image_size('woocommerce_single');
  remove_image_size('woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail');
  remove_image_size('shop-preview');
}
```

### Regenerate the media

.. by using plugins like https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ and it will work like a charm.

[broken image vs clean original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO8tO.png)